# DX DateEdit controls break inside of an ACT Accordion control

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got several DevExpress DateEdit controls on my page organized into an AjaxControlToolkit Accordion along with other fields relevant to my data.

The DateEdit controls worked quite fine until I put them into the Accordion so I'm assuming the problem is some conflict between DevExpress and AjaxControlToolkit though I have no other alternative unless there's a DX accordion type control that does the same as the one from the Control Toolkit...

The error I'm getting in my browser when I try to use a date editor is

> ASPx is not defined

No other details that I could find but DateEdit fields placed outside of the Accordion work perfectly.

Note that removing the accordion is not a viable solution for this project without a possible alternative being presented.

Here's my code:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajax" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upAlerts">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <ajax:Accordion runat="server" ID="Accordion1" EnableViewState="true" CssClass="panel panel-info"
                HeaderCssClass="panel-heading" ContentCssClass="panel-body">
                <Panes>

                    <ajax:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="apAlert">
                        <Header>
                            <h3>Alert Details</h3>
                        </Header>
                        <Content>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="dtDate">Date</label>
                                <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="dtDate" runat="server" DisplayFormatString="yyyy/MM/dd" CssClass="form-control"></dx:ASPxDateEdit>
                            </div>
                        </Content>
                    </ajax:AccordionPane>

                </Panes>
            </ajax:Accordion>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

​I would normally suspect the problem to actually exist with the ViewState since I know these controls (ACT ones in particular) can mess with the ViewState quite a lot, but the Accordion isn't currently disabling the ViewState so I'm prepared to rule that out as a possibility at this point.

That said, I'm all out of ideas.

I even tried to rearrange the order in which the assemblies are registered on the page so that DevExpress is being registered after Ajax in an attempt to ensure that Ajax wasn't overriding anything that DevExpress needed.

As a last resort I tried switching the DevExpress date editors to Ajax calendar extenders but for some weird reason they don't render correctly either (no dates are visible on the calendar pop out).

How can I get these DateEdit controls working?